# when replace has the same behavior as replacesAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace, replaceall

```
> "a a a a aa".replace(/ /, "b")
'aba a a aa'
> "a a a a aa".replace(/ /g, "b")
'ababababaa'
```

Can you explain why adding the `g` causes `replace` to have the behavior of `replaceAll`?

Comment: Cause that's what it does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#description

Comment: I just Googled `"javascript regex g"` and got numerous hits that answered your question, including the [first hit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp). Did you not consider doing something similar before posting the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'g' flag stands for "global" and is used to specify that a regular expression should perform a global search. This means that the regex engine will search for all occurrences of the pattern in the input string, rather than stopping after the first match. By default, without the 'g' flag, the regex engine will return only the first match found.

Thats why in your first example it only replaced first occurence and in second  all of occurences

Answer (score 1):

This is because `g` in regular expression denotes all occurences (of space).